goland debug failed, err: ld: warning: -no_pie is deprecated when targeting new OS versions
After upgrading my MacBook Pro (i7) to version 15.2 (24C101) and debugging it in Goland, an error message appears: ld: warning: -no_pie is deprecated when targeting new OS versions， Afterwards, debugging failed, Debugger disconnected unexpectedly。
But after switching to other projects, this problem will not exist again. I am seeking help and hope to know how to solve the error or ignore this warning.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
